# Show tally after removing duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates

Not sure if I should just break out database for this, but would be interesting to see another solution to this problem.

I have some lines of text in a text file like...

```
Bill
Bill
Pete
Mary
Mary
Mary
```

I didn't want duplicates and achieved it like so...

```
f = open('cgi/log/ipAddressList.log', 'r')
uniquelines = set(f.read().split("\n"))
for line in uniquelines:
    print line 

f.close()
```

Which gives me...

```
Bill
Mary 
Pete
```

but now I would like to tally how many instances they appeared in the text file like...

```
Bill (2)
Mary (3)
Pete (1)
```

Is there any kind of python magic that would do this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Cool, I looked into collections and came up with,

```
f = open('cgi/log/ipAddressList.log', 'r')
c = collections.Counter( f.read().split("\n") )
uniquelines = set(c)

for line in uniquelines:
        print line + '%s (%d)' % (line, c[line])

f.close()
```

Just noticed the new comment about the readlines() so thanks for that too.

Here's my dictionary solution...

```
f = open('cgi/log/ipAddressList.log', 'r')
l = list( f.readlines() )
d = {}

for i in set(l):
    d[i] = l.count(i)

print d
```

Comment: Read about `collections.defaultdict`.  Then rewrite your question to include any questions on `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 3):

[`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) might do what you're looking for.

Example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = ['Bill', 'Bill', 'Pete', 'Mary', 'Pete']
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> c
Counter({'Pete': 2, 'Bill': 2, 'Mary': 1})
>>> for k,v in c.items():
...     print(k,v)
...
Pete 2
Bill 2
Mary 1
```

You can apply this to your case with:

```
Counter(f.read().split("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you think about counting in Python, you (almost) all the time should be thinking about dictionaries. Here's a possible solution:

```
people = {}
for person in f:
    people[person] = people.get(person, 0) + 1
for person in people:
    print '%s (%d)' % person
```

Probably you won't need this here, but its better to use `f.readlines()` instead of doing the spliting yourself (`f.read().split("\n")`).